# Flutter - Isar schema is not defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-isar

I have decided to use [Isar database](https://pub.dev/packages/isar) in my next project and I find it much helpful when dealing with local data.

I followed the [quickstart guide](https://isar.dev/tutorials/quickstart.html) in its website. I added dependencies. Annotated the contact class. Ran code generator. But at fourth step, I have problem creating schema while creating Isar instance.

```
initIsar() async {
  final dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  final isar = await Isar.open(
    schemas: [ContactSchema],
    directory: dir.path,
    inspector: true,
  );
}
```

The problem is where I typed ContactSchema, it says

```
Undefined name 'ContactSchema'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

So question I have to ask is, I followed guide but I'm unable to create a schema. How can I create one to make Isar db work?

**UPDATE:**

```
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'contact.g.dart';

@Collection()
class Contact {
  @Id()
  int? id;

  late String name;
}
```

After adding `part 'contact.g.dart'`, type this command `flutter pub run build_runner build` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness of response:

Run (error? look at it, it likely say to remove isar from the first command)

```
flutter pub add isar isar_flutter_libs
flutter pub add -d isar_generator build_runner
flutter pub run build_runner build # Run every update of the collection
```

Example collection:

```
@Collection(accessor: "time")
class Timer {
  final Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  @Index(
    unique: true,
    replace: true,
  )
  late final bool isRunning;
  late final DateTime dates = DateTime.now();
}
```

Suggestion: (tree -x output)

```
$ tree -x
.
├── main.dart
└── model
    ├── timer.dart
    └── timer.g.dart

1 directory, 3 files
```

For how I'm using this:

```
void main() async {
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  final isar = await Isar.open([TimerSchema]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: flutter pub run build_runner build,  Worked for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

After you run the build_runner command the schema class is generated in the MODEL_NAME.g.dart file. you need to import that file to get access to the schema class.

Answer (score -3):

Hello Zahid If you want to add local db in your next flutter app there are various packgaes on https://pub.dev.

I would highly recomend you to go start with https://pub.dev/packages/floor it is easy to learn light weight to use..

Try this you would loved it.. and how to implement you can google it and here is a tutorial for how to use Floor in your flutter Mobile App.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQ7W7vpwTbk&t=1055s

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that.